# I want to show in index one select photo from multiple upload photos, in ruby on rails. How can i do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Post Model

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
    has_many_attached :images
end
```

Controller

```
params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, images: [])
```

Someone explain me....

Answer (score 0):

In Index, you can get the first image via:

```
@posts.each do |post|
  first_image = post.images.first # do something with it.
end
```

Comment: user select one photo, not first photo :(

Comment: Do you mean the user will choose an image and you want to handle the image?